# Как задать роуты в FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Задаю роуты через APIRouter

```
gateway_router = APIRouter()
gateway_router.include_router(gateway.router, prefix='/gateway', tags=['gateway'])
```

Если задать роуты таким образом - то в swagger всё появляется и работает корректно.

```
@router.get('/')
@router.post('/')
@router.put('/')
@router.patch('/')
@router.delete('/')
async def gateway(...):
```

Однако если попробовать вот так, то никаких ошибок нет - но и в `swagger` не отображается

```
@router.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"])
async def gateway(request: Request):
    pass
```

Comment: 1 - Вообще, это странная идея, делать один и тот же обработчик для разных HTTP методов. 2 - а чем первый вариант не устраивает?

Comment: @insolor вопрос не в том что удобнее, а почему второй вариант не работает

Comment: Вы буквально сформулировали вопрос "Как задать роуты в FastAPI?", ответ - используйте первый вариант, раз он работает. Если вопрос в том, почему второй вариант не работает, так и спрашивайте об этом)